# Is there 'domain' attribute in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

```cs
public class CreateParams
{
  [Required]
  public string Number { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; } // It has to be 'PREMIUM' or 'GOLD'
}
```

Is there 'domain' attribute?
I want the 'Type' is 'PREMIUM' or 'GOLD'.

Comment: What do you mean by "domain attribute"?  Are you asking for an attribute that would validate the value of the field?

Comment: @squillman Yes. right. I saw the keyword when I studied database. so I think It means that.

Comment: Are you looking for [Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Comment: @Nikki9696 Thank you so much! I didn't think Enum! HM.. enum can be strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a regular expression on this like

```
[RegularExpression("(PREMIUM)|(GOLD)")]
public string Type { get; set; } // It has to be 'PREMIUM' or 'GOLD'
```